# Windows Phone 7: delay in mp3 streaming

Tags: c#, streaming, mp3, windows-phone

I have a problem with streaming of audio on windows phone 7 (nokia lumia 800):

The app is windows phone 7.1, I have tried it on nokia lumia 800 (WP7.8) and lumia 820 (WP8.0)

I put a URL ( http://abc.radiostreaming.dk/ )  into my playlist:

```
AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(this.streamURI, "FOO", "BAR", "", null);
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = track;
```

I subscribe to BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged with different eventhandlers to change the UI (change button back and forth between "play" and "stop", and update "now playing"-textfield)

When I press play, the UI updates via the eventhandler to show a "buffering" icon, and then change that to "playing" again when BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState changes to PlayState.Playing.

On a nokia lumia 820 UI and sound works as expected, on lumia 800 BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged fires (changes to "Playing") and there is a faint tick in the headphones, but then there is a 5-6 second delay before the music starts playing.

The delay is of course annoying (the sound plays almost instantly on the 820), but that is acceptable if I can detect it and update the UI accordingly, that is not working right now using only

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged.
```

Any ideas on other event I can subscribe to, or ways to tweak how fast the sound starts playing (tweaking buffering perhaps? no luck with that so far....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a workaround: when I get

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged -> PlayState.Playing
```

I check the BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Position.Milliseconds, if it is 0 the stream is not really playing, so I just recheck every 100ms and then only change the UI from "buffering" to "playing" when BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Position.Milliseconds > 0

It solves the problem, but is a bit more messy than you would prefer, oh well :)

Answer (score 0):

First, rule out connection issues to the server.  Are both devices on the same WiFi connection?  If so, try this stream URL from [WAUG](http://waug.fm) which I have set up with a large initial buffer flush:

```
http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k
```

Some devices and software attempt to begin decoding, but quickly realize they do not have enough data.  Some decoders require more data than others.  Is there a way you can increase your buffer size before playing?  If not, you might have to manage this buffer yourself and pick a larger size.

Comment: Well it gets the track to play from the server (it makes an HTTP GET and the server returns the actual track to play, so we dont have to release a new app if the track changes) so the internet/WiFi connection should not be an issue. We pop up a warning MessageBox if there is a problem with the network. I probably need to tell the app to use a shorter buffer as a workaround.....

Comment: http://143.226.75.100/waug_mp3_128k has the same problem: there is a "tick" in the speakers/headphones and BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged changes to playing, but there are several seconds before the actual music plays.....

Comment: @FelixHJ, Strange.  Does that initial tick sound like it goes with the music that you hear later?  Is there a chance it is a leftover audio buffer from whatever was playing on the device previously?

Comment: Hmm not really, it's just a generic "soundcard initialised"/"amplifier started" tick, it's just noise. However, it appers at the exact same time as "BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged -> playing".